# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (in Winston)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, winston

I am getting the following error with my Winston Transport in the express backend of my MERN app:

```
error: uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at DerivedLogger.add (/Users/user-2/bulk-code/platform-v2/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:344:45)
    at DerivedLogger.transportEvent (/Users/user-2/bulk-code/platform-v2/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:628:14)
    at LegacyTransportStream.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at LegacyTransportStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at LegacyTransportStream.transportError (/Users/user-2/bulk-code/platform-v2/node_modules/winston-transport/legacy.js:32:10)
    at exports.Papertrail.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at exports.Papertrail.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at exports.Papertrail.Papertrail._silentErrorEmitter (/Users/user-2/bulk-code/platform-v2/node_modules/winston-papertrail/lib/winston-papertrail.js:479:8)
    at TLSSocket.onErrored (/Users/user-2/bulk-code/platform-v2/node_modules/winston-papertrail/lib/winston-papertrail.js:236:8)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

The code for my logger looks like this:

```
import { object } from "joi";
const winston = require("winston");
require("winston-papertrail").Papertrail;

const levels = {
  error: 0,
  warn: 1,
  info: 2,
  http: 3,
  debug: 4,
};

const level = () => {
  const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
  const isDevelopment = env === "development";
  return isDevelopment ? "debug" : "warn";
};

const colors = {
  error: "red",
  warn: "yellow",
  info: "green",
  http: "magenta",
  debug: "white",
};

const format = winston.format.combine(
  winston.format.timestamp({ format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:ms" }),
  winston.format.colorize({ all: true }),
  winston.format.printf(
    (info: any) => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`
  )
);

var console = {
  level: "debug",
  handleExceptions: true,
  json: false,
  colorize: true,
};

var error_file = {
  filename: "./src/logger/logs/error.log",
  level: "error",
  handleExceptions: true,
};

var file = {
  level: "info",
  filename: "./src/logger/logs/app.log",
  json: true,
  maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
  maxFiles: 5,
  colorize: true,
};

var winstonPapertrail = {
  host: "logs5.papertrailapp.com",
  port: 32019,
};

const transports = [
  new winston.transports.Console(console),
  new winston.transports.File(file),
  new winston.transports.File(error_file),
  new winston.transports.Papertrail(winstonPapertrail),
];

//catches uncaught errors
const exceptionHandlers = [
  new winston.transports.File({ filename: "exceptions.log" }),
];

const Logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: level(),
  levels,
  format,
  transports,
  exceptionHandlers,
  exitOnError: false,
});

export default Logger;
```

Can anyone help where this bug could be occurring? The app runs fine, but it just throws this error after several hours of being in idle mode in the terminal. I do understand somewhere a variable is being returned null but I am not really sure where. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" suggests that the transport.log object is undefined, and you're trying to access its 'length' property. Implementing the null safety in your code will solve this problem.
const target =!isStream(transport) || transport?.log?.length > 2? new LegacyTransportStream({ transport }): transport;

"?."--- using this while trying to access the length of the log property will resolve this issue. In JavaScript, the ?. (optional chaining) is an operator introduced in ECMAScript 2020 (ES11) that allows you to safely access properties or call methods on an object without having to explicitly check if the object and its properties are defined. It helps to avoid "Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" or "Cannot read property 'y' of null" errors.

Hope this helps. Good luck!